# Can I replace "so that" by something more pretty?

Tags: sentence-construction, informal-language

*I'm providing a reference to the paragraph **so that** you can understand the context*

I feel this sentence is a bit like a formal statement. Is this actually true? Is there a more relaxed way to say it?

Comment: You may omit **"that"**

Comment: I don't think there's anything "formal" about saying "so that".  It's a perfectly informal, natural way to say it.  If anything else, any other structure is likely to sound *more* formal.  (for example, "in order that")

Answer (score 1):

You use of "*so that*"

> I'm providing a reference to the paragraph **so that** you can understand the context.

might be replaced with "*in order that*"

> I'm providing a reference to the paragraph **in order that** you can understand the context.

both are not necessarily *formal* and have equivalent meanings.
It is a stylistic choice.

Comment: "In order that" is very formal in my opinion. I double checked with a number of references, and they agree with me. For example. Learning English from the BBC World Service says [so that is more common and less formal than in order that](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv146.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

As SovereignSun mentions, "so that" can be made less formal by removing "that".

In addition, other factors make your original sentence rather formal:

- "I'm providing" - self-referentially describing what you're writing is rather formal. "I am providing" would be even more formal. "Here's" would be less formal.
- "reference" is rather formal. "link" would be less formal.

Making it all less formal:

> Here's a link to the paragraph so you can understand the context.